# Why can't I use WITH statement in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to execute the following query in sqlite3:

```
WITH
    MATCHES AS(
        SELECT      CSV2.*
                    , CSV1.ROW as ROW_1
                    , CSV1.C4 as C4_1
                    , CSV1.C5 as C5_1
        FROM        CSV2
        LEFT JOIN   CSV1
        ON          CSV1.C4 LIKE '%' || CSV2.C2 || '%'
    ),
    EXACT AS(
        SELECT      *
        FROM        MATCHES
        WHERE       C4_1 = C5_1
    ),
    MIN_ROW AS(
        SELECT      C1
                    , min(ROW_1) as ROW_1
        FROM        MATCHES
        WHERE       C1 NOT IN (SELECT C1 FROM EXACT)
        GROUP BY    C1, C2, C3, C4, C5
    )
    SELECT      *
    FROM        EXACT
    UNION
    SELECT      MATCHES.*
    FROM        MIN_ROW
    INNER JOIN  MATCHES
    ON          MIN_ROW.C1 = MATCHES.C1
    AND         (MIN_ROW.ROW_1 = MATCHES.ROW_1 OR MIN_ROW.ROW_1 IS NULL)
    ORDER BY    C1
```

But I receive a syntax error near "WITH" statement.

I am executing the query using Python and the following versions:

sqlite3.version is 2.6.0 and sqlite3.sqlite_version is 3.6.21

Comment: Why you say you can't use it? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: @PauloScardine Yes. It says `OperationalError: near "WITH": syntax error`

Comment: And the same query runs OK on the sqlite3 prompt? (perhaps you need RECURSIVE)

Comment: Can you give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with a handful of sample rows of the CSV file (or, better, with `rows` just hardcoded into the program) so we can run this?

Comment: @PauloScardine I haven't tried sqlite3 prompt.

Comment: You meant SQLite's `WITH` statement, NOT pythons `with`, right? I edited accordingly. Feel free to revert back if my assumption is wrong!

Comment: Using tabs doesn't improve clarity, it prevents us from running your example without first converting it (especially since when you copy and paste from SO you're going to get spaces rather than tabs).

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Yes! I meant SQLite's WITH statement. I put Python just to tell that I'm using it in Python and not elsewhere. But editing it is fine since Python is tagged. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @amy it is a good idea to try it on the sqlite3 prompt just to make sure the error is related to Python.

Comment: I updated your question and removed the Python parts because in effect your problems is with the query and all the python bits are just confusing everyone (especially as there is a with statement in Python as well). I think now it better reflects your actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> sqlite3.version has given me 2.6.0 and sqlite3.sqlite_version has given 3.6.21. I have no idea why there are two different versions for it. I'm working on Python 2.7.

The "why" is [explained in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.version): the first is the version of the Python `sqlite3` module (or, rather, the separately-developed [`pysqlite`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite) module that the stdlib module tracks); the second is the version number of the SQLite library itself that Python (or `pysqlite`) was built against. Python can build against pretty much any version of `sqlite`.* So, you can have Python 2.7.9 with SQLite 3.2, or 2.7.5 with SQLite 3.8.

Most Windows users use the official Python binary releases, rather than building it themselves. These usually have a pretty up-to-date version, but if you're using an ancient binary, it was probably built with an ancient `sqlite`.

And that's the key here. If you look at [the changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), you can see that "Added support for common table expressions and the WITH clause" didn't happen until 3.8.3, and you're using 3.6.21.

So, what are your options?

- Get a newer Python binary that's built with sqlite 3.8.3 or later. I think the current 2.7.9 official binary for Windows should qualify.
- Build Python yourself against a newer sqlite.
- Get or build the third-party `pysqlite` module with sqlite 3.8.3 or later, and use `pysqlite.sqlite3` instead of just `sqlite3`. I'd assume that the package in [Christoph Gohlke's](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysqlite) repository is new enough, but I won't promise that.

---

<sub>* Well, 3.0 or later. For a while, Python 2.7 was broken if you tried to build against 3.0-3.4, but they intentionally fixed that, to allow people to build the newest Python with their platform's ancient sqlite.</sub>